# Powershell - xml

Tags: html, xml, powershell, replace, character

I have an input XML file which contains normal HTML names for various characters e.g. Double Quote = `&quot;` etc.

```xml
<Notes>Double Quote &quot; Single Quote &pos; Ampersand &amp;</Notes>
```

Before

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="8">
    <OrganisationId>ACME24/7HOME</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>ACME LTD</OrganisationName>
    <Notes>Double Quote &quot; Single Quote &pos; Ampersand &amp; </Notes>
    <Sector>P</Sector>
    <SectorDesc>Private Private &amp; Voluntary</SectorDesc>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

After

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="8">
    <OrganisationId>ACME24/7HOME</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>ACME LTD</OrganisationName>
    <Notes>Double Quote " Single Quote ' Ampersand &</Notes>
    <Sector>P</Sector>
    <SectorDesc>Private Private & Voluntary</SectorDesc>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

I am treating the file as XML and it gets processed OK, nothing very fancy.

```bsh
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path\$File)
foreach ($CMCAddressesRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow) {
    blah
    blah
}
$xml.Save("$path\$File")
```

When the output is saved all the HTML codes like `&quot;` get replaced by `"`.
How can I retain the original HTML `&quot;` characters? And more importantly why is it happening.

Comment: Should line 6 of the XML file have `&apos`?

Comment: System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode

Comment: It appears that the replacement of &quot; and &apos has already occurred when the file is read as [xml].

Comment: It's `&apos;`, not `&pos;`, and the `&amp;` are preserved in the output. When posting examples please make sure they're correct. Create a [mcve] and copy/paste that. Do not type from memory. Do not make things up.

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is called "character entities". PowerShell converts them on import, so you can work with the actual characters these entities represent, and converts on export only what must be encoded in the XML file. Quotation characters don't need to be encoded in a node value, so they're not being encoded on export.

Comment: sorry about the typo - my fault.
I have found that by using [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($var) I can do pretty much what I was looking for.
$dbl = '"'
(Get-Content $path\$InFile) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '(?is)(?<=<Notes>.*?)"(?=.*?</Notes>)', [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($dbl) } | Set-Content $path\$InFile

This will take the " double quotes and replace it with &quot; - very crude but I'm sure it can be improved.

Comment: Indeed. The examples can be validated at [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).